# How does 8-bit computers emulator work on modern days computer if the 8-bit computers software is proprietary? Do they need a permission?

Tags: emulation

How does 8-bit computers emulator work on modern days computer if the 8-bit computers software is proprietary?

I mean, that e.g. ZX Spectrum has a copyright on the stuff how it works etc. so how it is possible that there are legal emulators on the internet?

Comment: That's not really related to gamedev, is it?

Comment: Why not, I want to create one, so I am asking if I can or I cannot.

Comment: @Derfder that's more something software engineering related though. You could also emulate an x86. it doens't have to be for games. But I take that you need to understand the CPU architecture and the instruction sets that go with it and translate them to your current cpu .

Comment: Creating an emulator isn't creating a game. This should be migrated to stackoverflow.

Comment: It's an interesting question but please check the FAQ - it's off-topic under at least two headings: "what technology some particular game used" and "how to make (or start making) a particular type of game".  However, a clean room reverse engineer of the computer's BIOS (and subsequent emulation of that BIOS in software) would do it; historical precedent that establishes the legality of this includes the reverse engineering of the original IBM PC's BIOS (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_PC_compatible).

Comment: Hmm, I don't want to know how to write them. Right now I am concerned if it is ok/legal to do them. So, I think it is suited more for this forum. I am interested for now just if it is ok to make emulators or not. basially it is yes or no question, I guess ;)

Comment: On this page: http://voices.yahoo.com/what-emulators-roms-they-legal-352125.html?cat=19  I found this `Essentially, emulators are completely legal for creation, distribution, and use in the United States. There is no further interest from the United States Court System to hear any further cases on them.` What do you think about it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reverse engineering a particular system's hardware architecture and emulating it is apparently legal in most (if not all) jurisdictions. Otherwise you wouldn't find emulators for game consoles so easily. See [the link provided by Derfder in comment](http://voices.yahoo.com/what-emulators-roms-they-legal-352125.html?cat=19) for details on how this is considered by the US courts. This is for the hardware side of things.

But as you said yourself, the software running on those systems is most of the time proprietary. It's thus perfectly illegal to distribute ROMs for emulators without the owner's consent. If the owner doesn't care, then it's [abandonware](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abandonware) and you're in a grey area. Probably most of the ZX Spectrum games can be considered abandonware today, but I wouldn't be too confident either. That's why most emulators creators never ever distribute ROMs.

Comment: Also note that the original IBM PC's BIOS was reverse-engineered to create "IBM compatible" PCs back in the 80s, which sets a clear precedent.